# Is This A Valid Definition of Equality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Please excuse me if this question is obnoxious as I have no real experience with set theory. However, I have been thinking about the definition of equality and I came up with the following:

$$x=y \iff \forall A \ st. x\in A \Rightarrow y\in A$$

From this definition, it quickly follows that $y=x$. So is this a legitimate understanding? A few related questions on here "define" equality with some of its basic properties

Comment: It seems legitimate to me.

Comment: It's not obvious to me how you derive symmetry having that conditional in only one direction.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine say there exists a set, A, such that y is in it, but x is not. x then must be in the complement of that set A which implies (from the one sided condition in the definition) that y is in the complement of A. This is a contradiction as y cannot be an element of both A and its complement. Thus, every set that includes y must also include x

Comment: This is a little more subtle than that, because sets don't have global complements, they have complements with respect to particular sets of which they are subsets. But I see how it works in the presence of the Separation schema now. Though I'll add that in first order theories we don't usually define equality at all; it's just part of the underlying logic.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I guess this definition is implicitly depending on x and y being elements of a relative set.

Comment: I guess I don’t understand what you mean by equality not being defined at all...

Comment: I mean just what I said. In modern logic and set theory it's typically just an elementary, irreducible part of the language. We don't define equality any more than we define $\in$.